# How to move Download CSV link on Active Admin to action_item bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to move this link (see screenshot 2) to action_item bar like this
[image]

I did it so, but the link doesn't import filtered data now.

```
  action_item do
    link_to 'Export', some_path(:format => :csv)
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add params from request to link

```
action_item do
  params = request.query_parameters.except :format, :commit
  link_to 'Export', some_path(format: :csv, params: params)
end
```